# How to consume secured SOAP Webservice in Mule 4

Tags: mule4

Hi I have a Secured SOAP web service . I am able to hit from Soap UI successfully using the credentials .
When i am trying to configure the web service in any point studio i am getting a warning saying unable to get the metadata . But if run the application i am getting error while trying to connect to webservice.

```
Message : Error trying to acquire a new connection:null
```

I think the way i am setting up the credentials for the service is not correct . In Soap UI i am setting it as shown in screen shot . How to set it in Studio ? I tried the security tab in studio ,but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you are using the Web Service Consumer connector to consume an external SOAP web service. The screenshot shows that SOAP UI is using HTTP Basic Authentication. To reproduce that you need to configure the Web Service Consumer to point to an HTTP requester configuration that configures the HTTP authentication, as it mentioned in the official documentation:https://docs.mulesoft.com/web-service-consumer-connector/1.5/web-service-consumer-configure#setting-a-custom-http-transport-configuration

Example:

```
<http:request-config name="basic-auth">
    <http:request-connection host="www.someplace.com" port="8182" protocol="HTTP">
        <http:authentication>
            <http:basic-authentication username="alejandro.garcia" password="nariz"/>
        </http:authentication>
    </http:request-connection>
</http:request-config>

<wsc:config name="with-custom-transport">
    <wsc:connection wsdlLocation="http://www.host.com?WSDL" service="Service" port="Port">
        <wsc:custom-transport-configuration>
            <wsc:http-transport-configuration requesterConfig="basic-auth"/>
        </wsc:custom-transport-configuration>
    </wsc:connection>
</wsc:config>
```

Comment: Thanks and Yes this is the way the service expected to be called .